# Gridview is updated with SqlCommand but then edit and delete are no longer working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a gridview (bound to a SQL Server database), a textbox and a button.

I can delete or edit the values in the gridview. All works fine. No need to put any code myself, it is there by default.

However in the textbox I can put a value with a button to narrow down the result of my gridview.

Behind the button I have the below code. The result is shown in the gridview. Nice... Unfortunately as of then the  "delete" nor "edit" are working anymore.
I get :

> GridView fired event RowEditing which wasn't handled

Why would I write code myself in the `RowEditing` event if by default it is not required ? What am I doing wrong ?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [DbPeople].[Info] WHERE username like '" + TxtUsername.Text + "%'", conn);
conn.Open();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "info");

GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Thanks for some help.

Filip

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Are you originally binding your GridView to some sort of [ObjectDataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a4kyhcx.aspx) via the `DataSourceID`? If so, those are generally built to handle stuff like editing and deleting and therefore don't necessarily require you to handle those events yourself. When you bind by setting a `DataSource` like in your code above, you don't get that luxury.

Comment: @marc_s, you are right about the SQL injection. Will take care of that. Thx.

Comment: @j.f. my gridview is bound like this :
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">


And the SqlDataSource1 looks like :
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DbInfoConnectionString %>" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Info] WHERE [id] = @original_id"
            InsertCommand=... etc...

Comment: That would make sense then. I can't see your entire implementation, but since you are using an `ObjectDataSource`, my guess is that your architecture alongside this `ObjectDataSource` is handling those events for you. From the MSDN link in my previous comment: "(it is common that) the ObjectDataSource works with a middle-tier business object to select, insert, update, delete, page, sort, cache, and filter data declaratively without extensive code."

Comment: Since after you filter your DataSource, you no longer use the ObjectDataSource, you must handle all of the events yourself. Nothing is there to do it for you.

Comment: @j.f.  Your input was most valuable !!
I found a solution.
On button click I change the SQL statement and assign it back to the SqlDataSource.and 
     string sSQL = "select *..."
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sSQL;
            ViewState.Add("MySQL", sSQL);

And In the page load :
            if (ViewState["MySQL"] != null)
            {
                SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = (string)ViewState["MySQL"];
            }
This works fine.

Comment: Great, glad you were able to figure it out! Feel free to post your own answer to this question and also accept it. This may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the input of @j.f. I found out what went wrong and how I could resolve it.

Instead of changing the `DataSourceID`, I kept it but **changed the SelectCommand** on button click. Then I added it to the **viewstate**.

And on a new page_load, I pick up the new SQL statement from the viewstate.
That works fine! Don't have to write any code for the edit or delete.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I don't use this anymore :

    //            GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
    //            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    ...
    // now I do this :

    // New query string to narrow down the selection based on the input
    string sSQL = "select ...";
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = sSQL;
    ViewState.Add("MySQL", sSQL);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LblResult.Text = "";
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    if (ViewState["MySQL"] != null)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = (string)ViewState["MySQL"];
    }
}
```